# How to define vertical line correctly in axis environment?

Tags: plot, vertical

I Would like to have three vertical dottetd lines from top to bottom to visibly divide the 4 functions. How can I do this.

```
    \documentclass[letter,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $\beta$,
    ylabel = {$E[\pi_B(\beta)]/10^4$},
]
\addplot [
    domain=1875/497:4, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red    
]
{5*(-(1/3) + 5/x)};

\draw[fill] (3.2,4.5) circle (2pt) coordinate (a);

\addplot [
    domain=2500/741:1875/497, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red    
]
{ 50/3 / x};

\addplot [
    domain=625/196:2500/741, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red  
]
{ 5*(1/5 + 5/2/x)};

\addplot [
    domain=305/97:625/196, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red
]
{ 5*(1/3 + 2/x)};

\end{axis}
\draw[dotted] (1875/497, 4.4) -- (1875/497,5);
\end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say what the "best" way is, but here is a possible way.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,standalone]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $\beta$,
    ylabel = {$\alpha$},
]
\addplot [
    domain=1875/497:4, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red    
]
{5*(-(1/3) + 5/x)} coordinate[pos=0] (x1);

\addplot [
    domain=2500/741:1875/497, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red    
]
{ 50/3 / x} coordinate[pos=1] (x2);

\draw[dotted] (x1) -- (x2);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, to the way I made my example your answer is awesome. But what would i have to do that if the right function would not begin at the top? How can i just draw a straight line from (3.7, 4.4) to (3.7,5)?

Comment: @user34047 Why `3.7`? You could do `\draw[dotted] (1875/497, 4.4) -- (1875/497,5);`.

Comment: "\draw[dotted] (1875/497, 4.4) -- (1875/497,5);" is exactly what I tried first, but somehow it does not work for me. Your coordinate solution was very elegant, but I also need the vertical between other coordiantes.

Comment: @user34047 Well, what can I say? If I insert `\draw[dotted] (1875/497, 4.4) -- (1875/497,5);` in my code, there is no problem. You do not provide an MWE, i.e. something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, so it is impossible to say why it does not work for you.

Comment: Ok, now it should be a full MWE, sry, my bad.

Comment: @user34047 If you add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` to your preamble and move `\draw[dotted] (1875/497, 4.4) -- (1875/497,5);` before `\end{axis}`, you get a beautiful dotted line precisely where you want it to be. Note that the way coordinates in the axis environment are treated changed after some version (`1.9`?) and you are running in backwards compatibility mode. That's the reason why one should always present an MWE.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use coordinates in the format (axis cs: x,y).
This is general and you can pick any two points anywhere.
Here is the code for only one line in the middle. You can add the other lines in the same way.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,standalone]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $\beta$,
    ylabel = {$\alpha$},
]
\addplot [
    domain=1875/497:4, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red    
]
{5*(-(1/3) + 5/x)} ;

\addplot [
    domain=2500/741:1875/497, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red    
]
{ 50/3 / x} ;
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:3.77,0) -- (axis cs:3.77,4.95);



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `pgfplots` versions after 1.11, you no need to write `axis cs:` before coordinates. It is sufficient to write `\draw[dotted] (3.77,0) -- (3.77,4.95);`